# How do I safely remove files from Xcodes compile sources?

Tags: ios, xcode, alamofire, compiler-warnings

Under `Build Phases` there is a section called `Compile sources`. There is a file there called `AFSecureityPolicy.m` from the `AFNetworking` library there that handles `SSL-pinning` that I don't want anymore. If I remove it from the list I get an error that says

> undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS_$_AFSecurityPolicy

Not being too familiar with how `Compile sources` work, is there any additional steps to take after removing the file from the `Compile sources`? Or are there perhaps any other files that are dependent on the one removed?

Comment: You cannot simply remove a file from a library and expect everything to work. Obviously, other files are using the class you have removed. You can disable AFNetworking SSL pinning by normal means, not just by removing the file.

Comment: @Sulthan Ok, thanks. How do I disable it by normal means?